# WiFi keeps turning off (logging out) automatically

Tags: iphone, wifi, jailbreak, ios

I own an iPhone 5 running on iOS 6.1.2. It is jail broken.

I connect to the internet via the university WiFi system, which provided each of us a unique username and password, and we have a set download limit.

After logging in through my iPhone, after about 10 minutes, the iPhone disconnects itself and reverts itself to my data plan.

I do not understand the cause for this. How can I rectify this? Are there any jailbreak tweaks availabe from cydia?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a windows 7 laptop logging out of the Wifi System, did you figured out a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your phone is determining that the data connection is stronger/faster than the wireless connection and is purposefully changing to the more powerful connection. To test if this is the case, you can disable Cellular data on your phone when you want it to be connected only to the wifi. Not an optimal solution, but one that guarantees your data plan is saved.

Disabling the Cellular Data is under Settings > General > Cellular > Cellular Data and disable the option.

If the phone continues to disconnect with Cellular Data disabled, it's possible that your phone is experiencing the access points in the area having a channel conflict either with each other or with other wireless broadcast points in the area. This can happen if someone has one of the portable wireless access points broadcasting or when the access points in the area are not properly configured (or are on automatic channel select). There is also a possibility that the access point nearest you is on channel 1 and iOS devices really tend to prefer channel 6 or especially 11.

I work for a company that provides public wireless access at various locations and have experienced all of the above possibilities at various points with customers on iOS devices. If you feel like any of the above possibilities are what's occurring, you'll have to contact your college's wifi tech support or IT ops department because the

Comment: I have read that come what may, it always prefers WiFi over 3G/EDGE/GPRS

Comment: I work as a technician for a company that provides public wireless hotspots, almost always the wireless hotspots are seen as stronger and thus preferred but occasionally I have customers experiencing the same issue. If it continues to disconnect every 10 minutes you're likely going to have to contact the wireless support for your college, because the issue is on their end and not your phone. There's possible channel conflicts as well as the fact that iOS devices prefer to be on either channel 6 or 11. Editing my answer to contain that fact as well.